# Calculating ranks in Stata when high values come first

Tags: list, stata

After sorting by state and then town population in Stata, I would like to create a variable that orders the values that have been sorted from largest to smallest. I would like to assign a 1 to the town with the largest population, and continue the list to the town with the smallest value. I would like to repeat this exercise for towns from 30 different states.

Since there are different numbers of towns, I can't just create a variable that goes from 1 - 100 for each state. I have tried various versions of the `egen` command, but each time I end up typing a lot of numbers, where I am pretty sure I should be able to do this with just a line or two of code. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Kindly warning: questions without code tend to get downvoted or voted to close by many on this forum (not me on this occasion).

Answer (score 2):

```
clear
input str2 state str7 city pop000
AL ALCity1 128
AL ALCity2 391
AL ALCity3 997
GA GACity1 208
GA GACity2 1090
FL FLCity1 534
FL FLCity2 302
FL FLCity3 90
FL FLCity4 119
end

bysort state (pop000): egen poprank = rank(pop000), field

sort state poprank
list, noobs sepby(state)
```